SimpleLocalize nested traduction isn't workin
I'm using next-intl and simpleLocalize for translation.
I'm currently upgrading monorepo from Pages Router to App Router of Next.
I've done what said in the doc of next-intl and it work pretty well. But I've a case that is not working
pages.category.videos and pages.category.videos.all
All the translation works fine, but in that case, I have the translation for pages.category.videos, but not pages.category.videos.all .
I suppose it's a problem of nesting because I have this in my terminal when I console.log :
pages: {
   category : {
        videos: 'videos'
   }
}

Should I not have :
pages: {
   category : {
        videos: 'videos',
         { all : 'Videos'}          
   }
} ?

Thank you for helping, I'll be there to answer any question or precision.
I tried to change the nesting function. I was using a custom function, I changed to use lodash, but I have the same issue
